# Find index of every n number in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a big data which I load and show on the page in chunks. Initially I load the first 50 items and after that on button click I get the next 25.

- So I have 50 items on initial page load. After button click I fetch +25 items and now I have 75.
- On the second button click I get the next +25 items and now I have 100 etc.

I need to find always the number that is ten places before the last number in the list.

- When my list size is 50 - I need to get the index of the 40-th element in the list.
- When my list size is 75 I need to get the index of the 65-th element in the list,
- When my list size is 100 I need to get the index of the 90-th element in the list.

** Simulation **

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  arr.push(i + 1)
}

let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    arr.push(i + 1);
  }
  console.log(arr);
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Add items</button>
```

How can be this done?

Is there better way than

```
let index = arr[arr.length - 11];
console.log(index);
```

Comment: var item = arr.length >= 11 ? arr[arr.length - 11]  : undefined

Comment: Is there a problem with  `arr[arr.length - 11]`?

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the element the right way, you can create an arrow function that fetches the 10th last element (or undefined in case the list is smaller then 10)

```js
var smallArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var bigArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

const tenthLastElement = (array) => array[array.length - 11];

console.log(tenthLastElement(smallArr));
console.log(tenthLastElement(bigArr));
```

Comment: I'm not really sure there is need for any branching here. If you try to get `arr.length - 11` from `[1, 2, 3]` that resolves to index `-8` and there shouldn't be anything for that key. You'd get `undefined`.

Comment: But is this what you want to get? it really depends on what the author would like to get in that case.

Comment: This is what you return right now anyway. From the description in the question, doesn't sound like author here would ever have an array with less than 50 items. So, the conditional check 1. shouldn't go in the `false` branch 2. would return the same value whether or not the conditional check is there.

Comment: you are correct, i'm modifing the answer (: thanks for the comment @VLAZ